# S3 bucket policy is not allowing Athena to perform query execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am performing Amazon Athena queries on an S3 bucket. Let's call it `athena-bucket`. Today I got a requirement to restrict this bucket over VPC Enpoints. So I have tried this S3 bucket policy:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [

       {
           "Sid": "VPCe and SourceIP",
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "NotPrincipal": {
               "AWS": [
                   "arn:aws:iam::**********:user/user_admin",
                   "arn:aws:iam::**********:root",

               ]
           },
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::athena-bucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::athena-bucket/abc/*"
           ],
           "Condition": {
               "StringNotEquals": {
                   "aws:sourceVpce": [
                       "vpce-XXXXxxxxe",
                       "vpce-xxxxxxxxxx",
                       "vpce-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                   ]
               },
               "NotIpAddress": {
                   "aws:SourceIp": [
                       "publicip/32",
                       "publicip2/32"

                   ]
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Please note that Athena has full permission to access the above bucket. I want to use the S3 bucket policy to restrict access from only certain IP addresses and VPC Endpoint.

However, I am getting `access denied error` although request is routed through VPC Endpoints mentioned in the policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena is an Internet-based service. It **accesses Amazon S3 directly** and does *not* connect via an Amazon VPC.

If you restrict the bucket to only be accessible via a **VPC Endpoint**, Amazon Athena will not be able to access it.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply, but I want to restrict s3 access to vpce and at the same time athena should able to access S3. Is it possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible because Amazon Athena cannot access via a VPC Endpoint.

Comment: Is there any other probable solution to this? I want to deny all vpce and ip's except some and also alow Athena with bucket policy! Thanks again.

Comment: `Deny` policies always override `Allow` policies. So, one option is _not_ to use a `Deny` policy, but add your limitations to any `Allow` policy that grants access to the bucket. Then, also `Allow` Athena to access the bucket. This will be possible because there is no `Deny` policy that overrides the Athena `Allow`. Remember -- access is denied by default, so you should just be careful about any policies that grant access to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a solution for you to get what you are asking for. The following policy condition allows actions from all of your VPC endpoints **and** Athena:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "VPCe and SourceIP",
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "NotPrincipal": {
               "AWS": [
                   "arn:aws:iam::**********:user/user_admin",
                   "arn:aws:iam::**********:root",
               ]
           },
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:s3:::athena-bucket",
           "arn:aws:s3:::athena-bucket/abc/*"
           ],
           "Condition": {
               "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                   "aws:sourceVpce": [
                       "vpce-XXXXxxxxe",
                       "vpce-xxxxxxxxxx",
                       "vpce-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                   ],
                   "aws:CalledVia": [ "athena.amazonaws.com" ]
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

The "ForAllValues" portion of the condition is what turns this AND condition into an OR.

Not sure how your IP restrictions would play with this, since you cannot tell which IPs Athena would be coming from.

Comment: I've been testing this and the ForAllValues:StringNotEquals 
On aws:CalledVia does not appear to work for queries.